# Tests with redux async action and axios

Tags: redux, mocha.js, sinon, chai, axios

I have been learning testing with

- mocha
- chai
- sinon
- enzyme

now I am testing a redux async application, and I want to know if the arguments provided to some API calls are correct, how do I do that?

I'm thinking of something like `axios.getCall().args` to get the arguments provided for the API call and then verify if they are correct but I can't find a command that matches what I am thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how,

first stub the method

`axios.post = sinon.stub().returns(Promise.resolve({ data: 'test' }));`

then dispatch the async action

```
store.dispatch(updateTodos(currentState))
    .then(() => {
        // this line would get the call and then get the argument
        let args = axios.post.getCalls()[0].args;
        done();
    });
```